# Using Highchart with Codeigniter

Tags: json, codeigniter, highcharts

I am using Highchart with Codeigniter. I am displaying project requests for different months.

The Graph is displaying fine but the x-axis values are showing numneric values (0,1,2...) instead of month names. Here is my controller code:

```
public function data()
{

$data = $this->project->get_data();

$ab = array();
$category['name'] = 'Category';

$series1 = array();
$series1['name'] = 'WordPress';

$series2 = array();
$series2['name'] = 'Code Igniter';

$series3 = array();
$series3['name'] = 'Highcharts';

foreach ($data as $row)
{
$category['data'][] = $row->month;
$series1['data'][] = $row->wordpress;
$series2['data'][] = $row->codeigniter;
$series3['data'][] = $row->highcharts;
}

$result = array();
$result1 = array();
array_push($result1,$category);
array_push($result,$series1);
array_push($result,$series2);
array_push($result,$series3);

$this->view_data['ctg'] = json_encode($result1, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$this->view_data['series_data'] = json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$this->load->view('chart_high', $this->view_data);
}
```

Given below is the chart_high view:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Line Chart</title>
<script type="text/javascript"      src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var test =
$(function () { 
                $('#container').highcharts({
       chart: {
           renderTo: 'container',
           type: 'column',
           marginRight: 130,
           marginBottom: 25
       },
       title: {
           text: 'Project Requests',
           x: -20 //center
       },
       subtitle: {
           text: '',
           x: -20
       },
       xAxis: {
           categories: []
       },
       yAxis: {
           title: {
               text: 'Requests'
           },
           plotLines: [{
               value: 0,
               width: 1,
               color: '#808080'
           }]
       },
       tooltip: {
           formatter: function() {
                   return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                   this.x +': '+ this.y;
           }
       },
      credits: { enabled: false },
       legend: {
           layout: 'vertical',
           align: 'right',
           verticalAlign: 'top',
           x: -10,
           y: 100,
           borderWidth: 0
       },

       series: <?php echo $series_data ?>
    });
            });

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/exporting.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I hardcode the categories as ["January","February"], then the  x-axis values are showing as January, February etc like the way I want.

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It looks like you should change your series data array. You can try make your data look similar to: [['month1',1],['month2',1]], it should work fine in your case.

Comment: When I use 
    print json_encode($result1, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
then the output comes as
[{"name":Category", "data":["January","February","March".."December"]}].
I just need to capture the data part and put in categories. 
Any help in doing this will be appreciated as I am at my wits' end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it using the following code:

```
    $result = array();

    array_push($result,$series1);
    array_push($result,$series2);
    array_push($result,$series3);

    $ctg=$category['month']; 

    $this->view_data['month'] = json_encode($ctg, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Then in chart_high view, I used

```
xAxis: {
           categories: <?php echo $month ; ?>
       },
```

Now the months are displayed in x-axis as January, February, March..etc.
I have searched in many forums including stackoverflow but didnt find any solution.

I am posting as it may help someone in future.